# How to load table-to-json plugin dependency in Vue?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, dependencies

I'm trying to figure out what is the way to use hierarchical dependencies in node.

I'm building a VueJs chrome extension using Vue CLI and vue-cli-plugin-browser-extension (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-browser-extension).
In the background file I need to use two dependencies:

1. jquery
2. table-to-json (https://www.npmjs.com/package/table-to-json)

table-to-json needs jquery in order to work

I installed the two dependency using node install and require the dependencies in the background fild. But when I try to run the background script I get this error:

> background.js:37 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>       at Object.f370 (background.js:37)
>       at n (background.js:1)
>       at Object.fe77 (background.js:37)
>       at n (background.js:1)
>       at Object.1 (background.js:1)
>       at n (background.js:1)
>       at background.js:1
>       at background.js:1 f370 @ background.js:37 n @ background.js:1 fe77 @ background.js:37 n @ background.js:1 1 @ background.js:1 n @
>   background.js:1 (anonymous) @ background.js:1 (anonymous) @
>   background.js:1 DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load
>   content for
>   chrome-extension://ljejdkiepkafbpnbacemjjcleckglnjl/js/background.js.map:
>   HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

table-to-json is not able to see jquery.
What am I missing?

This is my background file, package.json and vue.config.js:

backgroung.js

```
const jQuery = require('jquery'), $ = jQuery
const tableToJSON = require('table-to-json')
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service build --mode development --watch",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "table-to-json": "^1.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vuex": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.3.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-browser-extension": "~0.24.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    popup: {
      template: 'public/index.html',
      entry: './src/popup/main.js',
      title: 'Popup'
    }
  },
  pluginOptions: {
    browserExtension: {
      componentOptions: {
        background: {
          entry:  'src/background.js'
        },
        contentScripts: {
          entries: {
            script: 'src/content-scripts/script.js'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention it. In my background file I required the dependencies. I edited the original post with the background related code

Comment: `$` is an alias for `jQuery` so there should be only one `require` e.g. const jQuery = require(...), $ = jQuery

Comment: Just tried and it's not working. Same error. This is what I did. const jQuery = require('jquery'), $ = jQuery
const tableToJSON = require('table-to-json')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't applicable to Node dependencies in general. `table-to-json` is legacy jQuery plugin and relies on jQuery globals instead of JavaScript modules. It [expects `jQuery` variable](https://github.com/lightswitch05/table-to-json/blob/1.0.0/lib/jquery.tabletojson.js#L446) to exist in the scope where the plugin is executed.

This can be achieved by exposing jQuery globals explicitly:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Or by [configuring Webpack to shim](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming) `jQuery` variable, either globally with `ProvidePlugin`, or locally for `table-to-json` package with `imports-loader`. The latter can be achieved without modifying Webpack configuration [on plugin import](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/imports-loader/#a-hrefhttpswebpackjsorgconceptsloadersusagea):

```
require('imports-loader?jQuery=jquery!table-to-json');
```

Since `table-to-json` is not JavaScript module, it doesn't need to be imported to a variable because `tableToJSON === undefined` on import. It's supposed to be used as jQuery plugin, `$(...).tableToJSONCell`.